# How Can I Automatically Split a Large Video Into Multiple Videos Between 1 or 2 Second Black Screens?

Tags: video-editing

I have a large video where the scenes are split between black screens that are a second or 2 and I'd like them to be split into multiple mp4 files with the audio included automatically.  Can you provide the software and or instructions on how to do it?

Comment: ffmpeg has a filter called blackdetect that you may use to create a script to do the task.

Comment: Questions asking for Software recommendations are off topic. I recommend that you remove that part. Also, show us what you've tried and the research you've done.